# How to access yaml with complex keys

Tags: yaml-cpp

The file test.yaml .....

```
   ---
   map:
        ? [L, itsy] : ISO_LOW_ITSY(out, in, ctrl) 
        ? [L, bitsy] : ISO_LOW_BITSY(out, in, ctrl) 
        ? [L, spider] : ISO_LOW_SPIDER(out, in, ctrl) 
        ? [H, ANY] : ISO_HIGH(out, in, ctrl)
```

What command can I use to access one of these with yaml-cpp.  I can access the map as a whole, but not individual elements.

Here's what I am trying:

```
    YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");
    std::cout << "A:" << doc["mapping"] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LS1:" << doc["mapping"]["[L, spider]"] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LS2:" << doc["mapping"]["L", "spider"] << std::endl;
```

Here are my results:

```
    A:? ? - L
          - itsy
 : ISO_LOW_ITSY(out, in, ctrl)
: ~
? ? - L
    - bitsy
  : ISO_LOW_BITSY(out, in, ctrl)
: ~
? ? - L
    - spider
  : ISO_LOW_SPIDER(out, in, ctrl)
: ~
? ? - H
    - ANY
  : ISO_HIGH(out, in, ctrl)
: ~
LS1:
LS2:
```

If this is not yet possible in yaml-cpp, I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a type that matches your key. For example, if your key is a sequence of two scalars:

```
struct Key {
  std::string a, b;

  Key(std::string A="", std::string B=""): a(A), b(B) {}

  bool operator==(const Key& rhs) const {
    return a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b;
  }
};

namespace YAML {
  template<>
  struct convert<Key> {
    static Node encode(const Key& rhs) {
      Node node;
      node.push_back(rhs.a);
      node.push_back(rhs.b);
      return node;
    }

    static bool decode(const Node& node, Key& rhs) {
      if(!node.IsSequence() || node.size() != 2)
        return false;

      rhs.a = node[0].as<std::string>();
      rhs.b = node[1].as<std::string>();
      return true;
    }
  };
}
```

Then, if your YAML file is

```
? [foo, bar]
: some value
```

You could write:

```
YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");
std::cout << doc[Key("foo", "bar")];     // prints "some value"
```

## Note:

I think your YAML doesn't do what you intended. In block context, an explicit key/value pair must be on separate lines. In other words, you should do

```
? [L, itsy]
: ISO_LOW_ITSY(out, in, ctrl)
```

and *not*

```
? [L, itsy] : ISO_LOW_ITSY(out, in, ctrl)
```

The latter makes it a single key, with an (implicit) null value; i.e., it's the same as

```
? [L, itsy] : ISO_LOW_ITSY(out, in, ctrl)
: ~
```

(You can see this by how yaml-cpp outputs your example.) See [the relevant area in the spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2798057).